# Delay the close event on beforeClose of jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, animation, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following code with CSS Animations running on the `.in` and `.out` classes.
My problem is that the Dialog is closing instantly and you don't see the close animation happen at all. So I need a delay of ~500ms before closing the dialog;

```
$.extend( $.ui.dialog.prototype.options, { 
    modal: true, 
    open: function() { 
        $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').removeClass('out').addClass('in'); 
    }
});

$confirm.dialog({

    buttons: {

        "ok": {
            text:'Ok',
            click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        },

        "cancel": {
            text:'Cancel',
            click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }
    },

    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {

        $('.ui-dialog').removeClass('in').addClass('out');

    }

}).dialog('widget').appendTo('.dialogWrapper');
```

I tried adding `return false` into the `beforeClose`, and then manually calling the `.dialog('close')` function but that just runs an infinite loop, and hiding the dialog manually seems to be wasted code (not to mention the overlay for the dialog would need to be removed, also)

I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

Si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to run this and test it out, here's the code you'll need, it's a lot slicker too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialog() {
        $('#myDialog').on("dialogbeforeclose", function (event, ui) { });
        $('#myDialog').dialog({
            beforeClose: function myCloseDialog() {
                alert('Closing Dialog Now...');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but I would image something along these lines will get you where you want to be???

```
$.extend( $.ui.dialog.prototype.options, { 
    modal: true, 
    open: function() { 
        $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').removeClass('out').addClass('in'); 
    }
});

$confirm.dialog({

    buttons: {

        "ok": {
            text:'Ok',
            click: function() { closeDialog(this); }
        },

        "cancel": {
            text:'Cancel',
            click: function() { closeDialog(this); }
        }

    }).dialog('widget').appendTo('.dialogWrapper');

function closeDialog(element){
        $(element).removeClass('in').addClass('out');
        $(element).delay(500);
        $(element).dialog('close');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much David Lloyd Brookes for your reply; it was the springboard I needed to get to this code here:

```
// function to close dialog using css animations.
$.fn.animateDialogClose = function() {
    var $dialog = $(this);
    $dialog.parents('.ui-dialog').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
    setTimeout( function() { $dialog.dialog('close'); }, 500);
};


$confirm.dialog({
    buttons: {
        "ok": {
            text:'Ok', class:'btn red',
            click: function() {  }
        },
        "cancel": {
            text:'Cancel', class:'btn',
            click: function() { $(this).animateDialogClose(); }
        }
    }

}).dialog('widget').appendTo('.ui-dialog-perspective-wrapper');
```

There's still the unfortunate problem though that this only applies explicitly to the buttons set to it, and not to (for example) the 'X' close button or the escape key.
I'll upvote, but I don't think you've answered my question... there might not even be an answer :(

Comment: Try: $dialog.bind('dialogclose', function(event) { <your code> }});

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach. The `dialogue` function can take a `hide` property which accepts the following http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-hide

You could pass the `effect` `hide` and then set a `delay` of `500`, keeping the majority of your original functionality intact, eg.

```
$confirm.dialog({
    hide: {
        effect: 'hide',
        delay: 500
    },
    // etc...
});
```